# Require.JS: loading modules that are dependent on each other?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm just getting started with [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org) and I have a (hopefully) simple question.

I'm using jQuery and SlickGrid, and I have loaded all my modules at the top of my main.js file as follows:

```
require(["jquery", "underscore-1.3.1", "backbone-0.9.1", 
     "plugins/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min", "plugins/slick.core", 
     "plugins/slick.grid", "plugins/slick.dataview"], function($) { ...
```

This works OK in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari I get a few error warnings:

```
SlickGrid requires jquery.event.drag module to be loaded
require-jquery.js:1632Error: Module name 'underscore' has not been loaded yet 
   for context: _http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

SlickGrid is dependent on jquery.event.drag and Backbone is dependent on Underscore, and it looks like Safari dislikes them not being able to see each other.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should try the [Requirejs Order Plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#order)  to make sure the files are loaded in the right Order.

**UPDATE: Please See Post below! The Order Plugin is outdated! USE SHIMS**

PLZ See *Konga Raju* and *Simon Smith* Post!

Comment: This is incorrect and should not be the accepted answer. Use the `shim` config option as stated by konga raju

Comment: Downvoting - this answer needs to be re-evaluated or withdrawn because it encourages people to use deprecated code.

Answer (score 13):

`requirejs order plugin` is `deprecated`. See the [`requirejs documentation`](http://requirejs.org/) and use [`shim`](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim) loading instead of `order plugin`.